# Want to delete DataGridView column with Access database column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using VB2010 and Access2007

I want to be able to add/delete a column to/from an Access database and display the result in a DataGridView at run time using code.

My VB form has an AddColumn button to add and a DropColumn button to delete the column from the database and a GataGridView1 to display the result.

AddColumn adds the column to the database and the DataGridView.
DropColumn drops the column from the database but not the DataGridView.
That is my problem, how to remove the column from the DataGridView1 as well as the database!

I have tried in vain to find the solution to this problem and would welcome any of your suggestions.

This is my VB code

Imports System.Data.OleDb.

Public Class Form3

```
Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = I:/AccessDGV/dbAccessDGV.mdb")
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblContacts", con1)

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim bs As New BindingSource

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim conString As String = My.Settings.dbAccessDGVConnectionString
    Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection(conString)
    Dim CB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)
    bs.DataSource = dt

    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddColumn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddColumn.Click

    con1.Open()
    Dim sqladdcolumn As String = "ALTER TABLE tblContacts ADD COLUMN Extra1 Text"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqladdcolumn, con1)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da.Fill(dt)
        cmd.Dispose()
        con1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con1.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnDropColumn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDropColumn.Click

    con1.Open()
    Dim sqldropcolumn As String = "ALTER TABLE tblContacts DROP COLUMN Extra1 Text"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqldropcolumn, con1)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da.Fill(dt)
        cmd.Dispose()
        con1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con1.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind the datasource to the gridview. What's happening is the gridview is still bound to an "older" datasource which still has the column.

```
Private Sub btnDropColumn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDropColumn.Click

con1.Open()
Dim sqldropcolumn As String = "ALTER TABLE tblContacts DROP COLUMN [Extra1 Text]"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqldropcolumn, con1)

Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'clear the datatable.
    dt.clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmd.Dispose()
    con1.Close() 
    ' Rebind the datasource of the gridview.        
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    con1.Close()
End Try

End Sub
```

**UPDATE** Changed the query string.
I think the issue may lie in the query string. The column name that its trying to drop is Extra1 rather than Extra1 Text.

Comment: Thanks Kash for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't need it, but try add DataGridView1.Update();   and/or DataGridView1.refresh();  after this line "DataGridView1.DataSource = bs"

Comment: Edited the answer I gave. Take a look and let us know if it worked.

Comment: You need to clear the datatable as well before doing the fill method.

Comment: KashTried your 2nd suggestion and still not able to delete the column

Comment: Kash
Tried your 2nd suggestion and still not able to delete the column
Here is my code
Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            'Clear the datatable
            dt.Clear()

            da.Fill(dt)
            cmd.Dispose()
            con1.Close()

            'Rebind the datasource of the datagridview
            bs.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
            DataGridView1.Update()
            DataGridView1.Refresh()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con1.Close()
rudolf

Comment: I think the issue may be in the query string then. Seems like the column name has a space in it.